Apple shared album asset local and cloud identifiers issue
Run getCloudID with the actual local identifier and this works to return cloud identifier which I store for later use.  I run the getLocalID function and get error message stating "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'PHCloudIdentifier')".
Passing in ONLY string for local and cloud identifiers and not sure what the message means as doc from apple says it should work for the getLocalID function.
func getCloudID(localIdentifiers: String) -> String {
    var cloudIdentifiers = String()
    let library = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
    let iCloudIDs = library.cloudIdentifierMappings(forLocalIdentifiers: [localIdentifiers])
    for aCloudID in iCloudIDs {

        let cloudResult: Result = aCloudID.value
        switch cloudResult {
            case .success(let success):
                let newValue = success.stringValue
                cloudIdentifiers.append(newValue)
        case .failure(let failure) :
            let thisError = failure as? PHPhotosError
            switch thisError?.code {
                case .identifierNotFound:
                    print("Failed to find the cloud identifier for \(aCloudID). \(String(describing: thisError?.localizedDescription)))")
                default:
                    print("Error looking up the cloud identifier for \(aCloudID). \(String(describing: thisError?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }
    }
    return cloudIdentifiers
}

func getLocalID(cloudIdentifiers: String) -> String {
    var localIdentifiers = String()
    let library = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
    let localIDs = library.localIdentifierMappings(for: [cloudIdentifiers])
    for aLocalID in localIDs {
        let localResult: Result = aLocalID.value
        switch localResult {
            case .success(let success):
            localIdentifiers.append(success)
            case .failure(let failure) :
                let thisError = failure as? PHPhotosError
                switch thisError?.code {
                    case .identifierNotFound:
                        print("Failed to find the local identifier for \(aLocalID). \(String(describing: thisError?.localizedDescription)))")
                    default:
                        print("Error looking up the local identifier for \(aLocalID). \(String(describing: thisError?.localizedDescription))")
                }
          }
        }
    return localIdentifiers
}


Figured out what I was doing wrong on the getLocalID function in that I needed to have it map to array and set as the PHCloudIdentifier.
let localIDs = library.localIdentifierMappings(for: [cloudIdentifiers].map(PHCloudIdentifier.init(stringValue:)))
It worked and returned the local identifier on the device I was using.
